# Flash web apps, can I get source data

Tags: .net, flash, web

I want to create a .net application that will load a webpage containing a flash player for streaming music.

The app should be able to get the title of the current song being played. And maybe be able to put on diffetent songs.

I know with, for example, HTML, you can just get the content out of an element, but is this possible with a flash web app of any kind of company?

Thanks

Comment: Nope. The SWF & NET apps must be both coded to interact with each other. Could your NET app get the song info from same place as where SWF would be checking anyways (some JSON / XML / M3U8 / etc)? Telling the SWF to change songs requires you use **External Interface** in the SWF code. Something like **[this tutorial](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/)** or maybe this **[tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12010/Fun-with-C-and-the-Flash-Player-External-API)**

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, this seems like it could do the job if I had access to the source code of the web player app, but I don't :/